# value must be a string web scraping table

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping

I have been struggling on how do i get the text (the name and change) from td (the rows) on https://finance.yahoo.com/gainers to do that i have used selenium and interate through the table and finding the tag tr then after that to get the text checked the tr tag for any td then printed the td text

structure of the site

```
<html>
    <body>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>symbol</th>
                    <th>name</th>
                    <th>price</th>
                    <th>change</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>FMCCJ</td>
                    <td>Federal Home Loan Mortgage Corporation</td>
                    <td>4.7600</td>
                    <td>+28.40</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

it gives me the error `value must be a string` in the line `for row in table.find_element_by_xpath(tr):`

here is the whole  code

```
tablelocation=("""//*[@id="scr-res-table"]/div[1]/table/tbody""")
table=driver.find_element_by_xpath(tablelocation)
tr=driver.find_element_by_tag_name('tr')

for row in table.find_element_by_xpath(tr):
    rowtext=[x.text for x in row.find_element_by_tag_name('td').text ]
    print(''.join(rowtext))
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line

```
for row in table.find_element_by_xpath(tr):
```

with

```
for row in table.find_element_by_xpath("//tr"):
```

Also, this line is unnecessary:

```
tr=driver.find_element_by_tag_name('tr')
```